# Start-AzureVM: Getting struck continously

Tags: azure, powershell-2.0

Can anyone please tell me if there are any change for "Start-AzureVM" API? 
It is getting struck with following command

```
Start-AzureVM  -ServiceName (get-azurevm | where {$_.name -eq $VMName}).ServiceName  -NAME $VMName
```

Also help me on where to look for latest azure API changes?

Comment: No changes were made to this cmdlet. It worked absolutely fine for me. I tested that line of code right now. Check your Azure Subscription and make sure you Select it using Select-AzureSubscription. Can you give us more information probably a screen shot or more context on where exactly it is getting stuck.

Comment: What do you mean by stuck? Is it hanging, do you get an error?  Also, the change log for the Cmd Lets can be found at https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-tools/blob/master/ChangeLog.txt.

Comment: Thanks@ramiramilu:I have also tried following approaches and It is working fine 
 - added Select-AzureSubscription call to select azure subscription and then tried "Start-AzureVM  -ServiceName (get-azurevm | where {$_.name -eq $VMName}).ServiceName  -NAME $VMName". 

OR
 
 - with "Start-AzureVM -ServiceName $ServiceName -NAME $VMName" in this case my service name & vm name are same.

Comment: Thanks@MikeWo:It was in hanging state at "Start-AzureVM  -ServiceName (get-azurevm | where {$_.name -eq $VMName}).ServiceName  -NAME $VMName"call. But after using Select-AzureSubscription call it is working fine now. Thanks again for the change log location link.

Comment: @Amar do you mind if I add the content in my comment as an Answer, so that it would be helpful for other persons.

Comment: @ramiramilu: Yup, sure we can add it to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you select a valid Azure Subscription using Select-AzureSubscription cmdlet before you use Start-AzureVM cmdlet.

When you do not have a valid Azure Subscription, there is a potential chance for all other Azure cmdlets behave awkwardly like you mentioned in your question.